# How would I get the total of month in my newly created file?

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, methods

I'm currently working on C from this 
Option 3: Download Statistics

If the user chooses this option, the program will create a statistics file with the following data:

```
a.  Power output sorted from lowest to highest
b.  Day with highest output 
c.  Total by month 
d.  Average power output for all the data
```

The statistics file will have the same name as the input file but with _stats.txt appended to it. For example, if the input file was named data.txt, the stats file will be named data_stats.txt.

My data file contains

```
January 10 2018 236.9
January 11 2018 267.6
January 12 2018 278.1
January 13 2018 246.9
January 14 2018 262.3
January 15 2018 288.6
February 2 2018 199.7
February 3 2018 134.6
February 4 2018 200.8
February 5 2018 198.2
March 9 2018 169.7
March 10 2018 168.3
March 11 2018 179.4
```

When I run C my total power is 288.6, how do I get the sum of each month?

```
 public static void createStatsFile(ArrayList<Entry> uploadResults) {
    ///////////////
    ///////A///////
    ///////////////
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data_stat.txt", "UTF-8");

        ArrayList<Entry> lowestToHighest = bubbleSort(uploadResults);

        for(Entry entry : lowestToHighest) {
            writer.print(
                    "Month: " + entry.getMonth() + " Day: " + entry.getDay() + " Year: " + entry.getYear() + " Power Output: " + entry.getPowerOutput());
            writer.print("\n");
            entry.print();
        }

        ///////////////
        ///////B///////
        ///////////////
        Entry tmpEntry = null;

        for(Entry entry : uploadResults) {
            if(tmpEntry == null) {
                tmpEntry = entry;
            } else {
                if(entry.getPowerOutput() > tmpEntry.getPowerOutput()) {
                    tmpEntry = entry;
                }
            }
        }

        writer.write("Day of Max Power Outage: " + tmpEntry.getMonth() + " " + tmpEntry.getPowerOutput());

        ///////////////
        ///////C///////
        ///////////////

        //ArrayList<Entry> totalByMonth = bubbleSort(uploadResults);
        Entry tempEntry = null;
        for(Entry entry: uploadResults) {
            float sum;
            sum =entry.getPowerOutput();
        }

        writer.write("Total power output by month: " + tmpEntry.getMonthList() + " " + tmpEntry.getPowerOutput());
        writer.close();
```

My class:

```
public class Entry {
    //declaring variables
    private String month;
    private String day;
    private String year;
    private float powerOutput;
    private String file;
    private int[] MonthList;
    String inputFile = file;

    //Constructors
    public Entry() {
    }

    public Entry(String m, String d, String y, float p) {
        month = m;
        day = d;
        year = y;
        powerOutput = p;
    }

    //creating print to call ArrayList in main
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Month: " + month + " Day: " + day + " Year: " + year + " Power Output: " + powerOutput);
    }

    public static void getFile() {

    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public float getPowerOutput() {
        return powerOutput;
    }

    public int[] getMonthList() {
        return MonthList;
    }

    public String getInputFile() {
        return inputFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Entry` here?

Comment: oh sorry it's my class, I should've showed that too

Comment: Tip: Use standard ISO 8601 formats when storing dates as text: YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams to get a Map of the required results.

```
 Map<String, Double> collect = uploadResults.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getMonth, Collectors.summingDouble(Entry::getPowerOutput)));
```

Working

```
List<Entry> uploadResults = Arrays.asList(
        new Entry("January","10","2018",236.9f),
        new Entry("January","11","2018",267.6f),
        new Entry("January","12","2018",278.1f),
        new Entry("January","13","2018",246.9f),
        new Entry("January","14","2018",262.3f),
        new Entry("January","15","2018",288.6f),
        new Entry("February","2","2018",199.7f),
        new Entry("February","3","2018",134.6f),
        new Entry("February","4","2018",200.8f),
        new Entry("February","5","2018",198.2f),
        new Entry("March","9","2018",169.7f),
        new Entry("March","10","2018",168.3f),
        new Entry("March","11","2018",179.4f)
);

Map<String, Double> collect = uploadResults.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getMonth, Collectors.summingDouble(Entry::getPowerOutput)));

System.out.println(collect);
```

Output

```
{March=517.3999938964844, February=733.3000030517578, January=1580.3999938964844}
```

EDIT:

For versions below Java8, this should do

```
Map<String, Float> monthMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry uploadResult : uploadResults) {
    String month = uploadResult.getMonth();
    Float powerOutput = uploadResult.getPowerOutput();

    if( monthMap.containsKey(month) ){
        powerOutput += monthMap.get(month);
    }
    monthMap.put( month, powerOutput);
}
System.out.println(monthMap);
```

Comment: Okay I imported that but now i'm getting errors under map and collectors. Do I need to import something in java to use these?

Comment: This works only If you are using java8+. Imports should be `import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: Oh damn, I think my i'm using java 7 for my course, do you know how to do it manually? I was thinking of using a bunch of for loops with if statements but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Edited. You can use this. It's the elaborate version.

Comment: only error i'm getting is under the first Map, cannot find symbol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193221/discussion-between-nitro-and-blackpearl).

Comment: you're a saint, ty blackpearl

Answer (score 1):

Here you initialize your sum in every loop.

```
    Entry tempEntry = null;
    for(Entry entry: uploadResults) {
        float sum;
        sum =entry.getPowerOutput();
    }
```

Move the `float sum;` before the sum and add to the sum:

```
    Entry tempEntry = null;
    float sum = 0;
    for(Entry entry: uploadResults) {
        sum += entry.getPowerOutput();
    }
```

Comment: If i do that than I get an error under sum, variable not initialized

Comment: Edit: You need `float sum = 0;` before the loop.